# CakePHP 3: save method is always returning false, but my entity is fine

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

That's my `add()` method. When a customer is inserted I check if the `email` sent already exists on Users table and get its code. If not, the user is inserted:

```
public function add()
{
    $customer = $this->Customer->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $email = $this->request->data['email'];
        $queryUser = $this->Customer->Users
            ->find('all')
            ->select(['id'])
            ->where(['username' => $email]);
        $findUser = $queryUser->first();

        if($findUser){
            $idUser = $findUser->id;
        } else {
            $user = $this->Customer->Users->newEntity();
            $newUser = [
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => '123',
                'role' => 'customer',
                'active' => true,
                'email' => $email
            ];               
            $user = $this->Customer->Users->patchEntity($user, $newUser);

            if ($this->Customer->Users->save($user)) {
                $idUser = $user->id;
            } else {
                throw new NotFoundException('Não foi possível salvar o usuário');
            }
        }

        $this->request->data['user_id'] = $idUser;
        $customer = $this->Customer->patchEntity($customer, $this->request->data);
        $this->debugDie($customer);

        if ($this->Customer->save($customer)) {
            $retorno = $this->preparaRetorno(true, $customer->id, 'Customer');                
        } else {
            $retorno = $this->preparaRetorno(false, 'O cliente não pôde ser salvo', 'Customer'); 
        }

        $this->set(compact('retorno'));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'retorno');
    }
}
```

The entity created is fine. That's its debug:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Customer) {

    'nomecliente' => 'novo-cliente-sem-7',
    'cnpj' => '10252503627',
    'bairro_id' => (int) 1,
    'nomerua' => 'Contorno',
    'numero' => (int) 2905,
    'complemento' => '405',
    'pessoacontato' => 'José',
    'email' => 'novonovo@nn.lkj',
    'telefone1' => '3145555',
    'telefone2' => '988888',
    'cep' => '30110915',
    'país' => 'Brasil',
    'estado' => 'MG',
    'cidade' => 'Belo Horizonte',
    'user_id' => (int) 3,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'nomecliente' => true,
        'cnpj' => true,
        'bairro_id' => true,
        'nomerua' => true,
        'numero' => true,
        'complemento' => true,
        'pessoacontato' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'telefone1' => true,
        'telefone2' => true,
        'cep' => true,
        'país' => true,
        'estado' => true,
        'cidade' => true,
        'user_id' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Customers'

}
```

I activated the database log but there's no `INSERT` on the logs. This problem is driving me crazy! I don't understand why save() is always returning false, since my entity has no validation errors.

Thanks any help.

Comment: Debug your entity _after_ saving too. Application rules are applied in the saving stage, unlike validation rules, which are applied in the marshalling stage. ps, the ORM is able to save associations out of the box.

Comment: which save is not working ? customer save or user save ? first of all try replacing your all Customer by Customers in the function.

Comment: It can be because of your validation rules in model. So in your else debug the validation error. For `$user` in your else put `debug($user->errors());`  and for the `$customer` else part put `debug($customer->errors());`

Comment: @ndm that's it. I'm still adapting to CakePHP 3 and I didn't know I could debug the entity after saving. The `save` was returning false because of this error: `'email' => ['_isUnique' => 'This value is already in use']`

Comment: Very well readable documentation about this phenomenon can be found here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html